# Tab button in ftp command

Tags: linux, ftp, command, rename, aix

I usually use "TAB" button to help me do typing in linux or AIX command, for example, I have a file with file name is `abcdefg.txt`, so when I want to vi to this file, I just type `vi ab` then press the "TAB" button in my keyboard, then it will automatically help me search for `abcdefg.txt` (only have 1 file which is name start with ab).

However, when I ftp to the environment, I can not use "TAB" button, I need to fully type the whole file name. Please advise me how to do this in ftp environment.

Second problem, in ftp environment, when I list all the files in the directory, I saw a file which name is `123456789.txt`, however, when I want to rename it like:

```
rename 123456789.txt 123456789a.txt
```

it prompt me 550 123456789.txt: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

But I can rename the other files. I suspect this `123456789.txt` file name got some space in some where, that's why I hit the error.

Comment: You can try [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) which supports tab autocompletion. It may help you with the other issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Most FTP programs, especially those which come with proprietary Unices like AIX or HP-UX don't offer readline support. Install a more powerful tool like [`ncftp`](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) to fix this.

To rename files with whitespace, you can try to quote the file name but again, this might fail with bare-bones FTP clients.

When just downloading the file, there is a simple workaround: Use your browser. Every browser supports the `ftp://` protocol. The main problem here is security: You have to pass the password via the URL: `ftp://user:password@host/` so the browser will put it into its history.

But since you use FTP, security isn't a concern anyway (FTP transmits the password as plain text over the wire, so everyone on the same network can see it).

Another option is [mucommander](http://www.mucommander.com/), a cross platform file manager which supports a wide range of protocols and which handles spaces in file names correctly.